# Container implementation for complex type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to come up with a container wrapper which stores data of the following types: bool, int, double, std::string. In addition I have a complex type which I need to store in the container. Let's call it Foo. For the sake of simplicity we'll say that Foo contains a list of ints.

My container class currently wraps an ugly and complex container type which I get from a c api. When I'm finish manipulating the data in the container, I need to copy it back to the api. It uses unions and linked lists. It is possible that I can copy this data into, for example, a std::list, but this might cause performance issues which present themselves at a later date. Therefore, my container class is not dependant on how data is actually stored in memory.

Here's a quick idea of how my container looks:

```
template <class T>
class Cont
{
public:
    Cont(ISetter<T>* setter)
        : _setter(setter)
    {
    }

    void sillyFunction(T t)
    {
        (*_setter)(t,0);
    }

private:
    ...
    ISetter<T>* _setter;
};
```

So I use a helper setter class which handles the nitty gritty of the memory. I have a number of these class but the ISetter will give you an idea of what I'm doing.

In order to deal with the Foo type, which is also stored by the c api in a rather bizarre way, I have arrived at the following setter. Again, this is just a rough example.

```
class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual int getMember() = 0;
};

class Foo2: public IFoo
{
public:
    virtual int getMember(){ return 1;} // dummy 
};

template<typename T> class ISetter{};
template<> class ISetter<IFoo*>
{
public:
    virtual void operator()(IFoo* value, int index) = 0;
};

template<typename T> class Setter{};
template<> class Setter2<Foo2*>: public ISetter<IFoo*>
{
public:
    virtual void operator()(IFoo* value, int index)
    {
        _list[index] = dynamic_cast<Foo2*>(value);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Foo2*> _list;
};
```

So I handle my Foo as an interface called IFoo. The Setter2 implementation deals with the setting in memory of my list of Foos. Setter1, missing below, deals with the ugly c api memory.

Here's an idea of these class in practice:

```
Foo2* f = new Foo2();
ISetter<IFoo*>* setter = new Setter2<Foo2*>();
Cont<IFoo*>* container = new Cont<IFoo*>(setter);
container->sillyFunction(f);
```

When dealing with ints, for example, I do something like this instead:

```
int i = 10;
ISetter<int>* setter = new Setter1<int>();
Cont<int>* container = new Cont<int>(setter);
container->sillyFunction(i);
```

So, my question is if you think this is a good approach and what improvements you might recommend.

I use shared pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Stars and `new`s and classes-with-`I` make me dizzy... :-S

Comment: "a container wrapper which stores data of the following types: bool, int, double, std::string. In addition I have a complex type ... Foo." So, basically you want `boost::variant<bool, int, double, std::string, Foo>`. I think the overhead of copying in and out of that is smaller than the overhead of all the virtual-ness you now have.

Comment: No. Good approach for any container is to have interface that is close to similar containers in standard library. Then your container will internally have adapter to the C container and externally have interface like `std::list<>` or `std::deque<>`.

Comment: I don't know how ugly was the original C api, but this can be even more ugly, not to mention all the dynamic helper classes you have to create, maintain, destroy ...  Frankly, what is the objective of all that fuzziness?

Comment: @MSalters I have a boost::variant implementation also, but I got cold feet since there is a huge amount of data associated with certain containers. However it certainly feels like the simplest approach.

Comment: @Emilio Garavaglia: My plan was to use factories to create the containers with the correct helpers. These helpers can have different implementations depending on how the data is stored in memory.

Comment: @Baz what do you mean by "a huge amount of data associated with certain containers"? And how can your 30 lines of code (which doesn't actually work, requires a complex class hierarchy, complex memory management and *a lot* of virtual function call overhead) be a "simpler approach" than the one-liner of using the implementation that someone else has already written for you? Sounds more like the NIH syndrome than finding the simplest approach

Comment: @jalf I can receive, for example, a few thousand Foos from the C api. In order to manipulate this list, I wish to store them in a C++ container. If I copy all the data into a list::<boost::variant<...>> then I will incur a cost. When I'm finished manipulating the data, I need to copy it back to the same c api format as I received it in.

Comment: What I don't understand is how your implementation is supposed to reduce this cost. What cost do you think `boost::variant` has? (the correct answer is "none, really", whereas your implementation would make practically **everything** slower. Allocation, as well as accessing elements) -- Also, if you are at all concerned about performance, *why are you using a `std::list`?

Comment: @jalf I'm not using std::list, I'm using the ugly c implementation. That was just an example. The cost of boost::variant is that I have to opy data into it. I don't have that cost with the above code since it deals with the memory as I receive it from the c api.

Comment: @jalf Someone above suggested that I could use boost::variant<...>, so I need a container to store such objects in. I'm not sure which container is best in this respect, I had used std::vector myself when I tested this approach earlier. However, inserting items into the array is a very common operation which meant I hadn't ruled out the idea of using a std::list.

Comment: Leaving that aside for a moment, I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to achieve. Your example shows creating a container *just for ints*. So does that mean you might have a container of ints, and you might have a container of strings and you might have a container of Foo's? Or are you going to have a container which contains a mix of strings, ints, foos and whatever else?

Comment: @jalf Just of one type, no mixing. So is there any point in using boost::variant since I know which type will be returned by the c api?

Comment: Then why not just use a simple `std::vector<int>` for the simple types, and a `vector<Foo*>` for the Foo type which you don't want to copy? And you're right, then boost::variant makes no sense

Comment: @jalf yes I could write a templated function for traversing the data from the c api (which is stored in unions), returning a vector<T>. There is no notion of Foo or Foo* in the c api, rather a linked list of Foo members. Furthermore, a Foo member can be associated with a key where the key is of type bool, int, double etc. So maybe I can use a vector of pairs here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a single simple `Foo` wrapper class which can look up members data from the C API, and present it as a coherent class. No need for messing about with interfaces, virtual functions or inheritance for that. Just a single class will do.

So for each "Foo"-entry  in the C API, you create a single Foo wrapper.

Then you have simple, well-behaved type representing individual instances of the data stored in your C library.

Now just take that and put it in a `std::vector`.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(<handle-or-pointer-to-library-data>);

    // member functions for retrieving member data from the C API
};


std::vector<int>
std::vector<bool>
std::vector<std::string>
std::vector<Foo>
```

As I understand your problem, that would be a simple and efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would change it a little. Consider to remove all this Setter virtual-ism from your code. One of goal to introduce Templates were to have alternative to virtual-ism:

```
template <class T, class Setter>
class Cont
{
public:
    Cont(Setter setter = Setter())
        : _setter(setter)
    {
    }

    void sillyFunction(T t)
    {
        _setter(t,0);
    }

private:
    ...
    Setter _setter;
};
```

And its simple usage:

```
template <class IType, class Type>
class Setter2_Virtual
{
public:
    void operator()(IType* value, int index)
    {
        _list[index] = dynamic_cast<Type*>(value);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Type*> _list;
};


Cont<IFoo*, Setter2_Virtual<IFoo, Foo2> > container;
container.sillyFunction(f);
```

I concentrated on Setters - but maybe you can do the same with IFoo/Foo stuff as well.

Just an idea - you do not obliged to use it after all.